# Find commonly joined queries in Redshift

Tags: join, optimization, amazon-redshift

I want to get a list of the most frequently joined tables in our Redshift.  Ideally with the join conditions.  Reason: we're adding sortkeys and distkeys, and trying to be relatively thorough (sidenote: if you have any good tips for optimizing query runtimes, I'm eager to hear).

I know I can query STL_QUERY to get querytext, runtimes, etc.  But aside from doing some manual text analysis, any way to see which tables are merged by query id?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not "STL" table in redshift, that can readily give out this information. As you mentioned, you would need to look at all the queries in [STL_QUERYTXT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERYTEXT.html) table and search for joins.

In terms of general performance tuning suggestions, I would suggest you look at persicope's [blog](https://www.periscopedata.com/amazon-redshift-guide) if you havent already. And there is [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-optimizing-query-performance.html).